# If $f(x + y) = f(x) + f(y) +xy$ and $f(4) = 10$ then $f(2001) = ?$ Why is my answer wrong?

Tags: functional-equations

I saw this question on YouTube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h98AElJPxa8

$f(x+y) = f(x) + f(y) +xy$, and $f(4) = 10$ then $f(2001) = ?$

The following is the way I solved it, and it looks right to me but they have a different solution in the video:

$f(a) = (a^2)/2 + 2$ => $f(x+y) = (x^2 + 2xy + y^2)/2 + 2$ => $f(x+y) = (x^2)/2 + 2 + (y^2)/2 + xy$

So that we have $f(x+y) = f(x) + f(y) +xy$, I define $f(x) = (x^2)/2 + 2$ and $f(y) = (y^2)/2$

Using: $f(a) = (a^2)/2 + 2$,
$f(4) = (4^2)/2 + 2 = 16/2 +2 = 8 + 2 = 10$

So if $a = 2001$ then $f(2001) = 2002002.5$ or $f(2000+1) = 2002002.5$

Which is different from the video. Are there multiple answers? Where am I going wrong? can $f(x)$ have a constant of $+2$ beside $(x^2)/2$?

Comment: $f(x) = (x^2)/2 + 2$ and $f(y) = (y^2)/2$ makes no sense. The first equation implies that $f(y) = (y^2)/2 + 2$

Comment: That makes sense

Comment: @MedhajPatel Welcome to Math SE. FYI, using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24f(x%2By)%3Df(x)%2Bf(y)%2Bxy%24%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24f(4)%3D10%24&p=1), there's the AoPS threads [A functional equation problem](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h2477113p20773612) and [f(x + y) = f(x) + f(y) + xy, f(4) = 10, f(2001)=?](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1919097p13157792) with your specific problem question, and [Question about a function defined by a functional equation](/q/2111893) here asks about something quite similar.

Comment: Why do you consider $f(a)=a^2/2 +2$? Computing $f(2)$ from given formula yields its value as $3$. But your formula fails here, it works only for $x=4$ (and maybe for few more numbers, but not all). **Don't generalize with a single piece of information**

Answer (score -2, accepted):

While finding whether $f(x) = x^2/2 + 2$ satisfies the given functional equation,you accidentally plugged $f(y) = y^2/2$ when it should have been $y^2+2;$ can you now verify whether your solution is valid or not?

Well now, returning to the functional equation $f(x+y) = f(x) + f(y) + xy$ notice that $f(z) = z^2/2$ is a possible solution to this. Plug in this solution to see what you get.

Comment: $f(z) = (z^2)/2$ is not a solution. In that case, $f(4) = 8$ which is not $10$

Comment: Yeah I didn't consider the initial condition; my answer was just meant to address the original functional equation. The part "Plug in this solution to see what you get" was essentially meant to verify the initial conditions and all, to see if the solution satisfies them or not. In this case it doesn't but often it gives us an idea of what could be a solution; in other words, solving a functional equation leaving aside the initial conditions is often good to come up with a guess, and then working on the guess to get the solution is often a good strategy.